# Any way to do one-to-one association by non primary key in spring data

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-one

**I have a situation where two entities are to be joined on non-primary key column. I have following situation:**

```
@Embeddable
Entity EmbeddedKey{
    private String apple;
    private String banana;
    private int cat;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity{

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbeddedKey embeddedKey;

    @Column(name = "dog")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger dog;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentEntity")
    @JoinColumn(name = "dog", referencedColumnName = "dog")
    private ChildEntity childEntitty;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ChildEntity{

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "dog", referencedColumnName = "dog")
    private ParentEntity parentEntity;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "dog")
    private BigInteger dog;
}
```

When I deploy code, i get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: ParentEntity.id of: x.y.z.ChildEntity.
```

As per me, hibernate is trying to join primary key of parent table with primary-key of child table which my design doesn't want. column dog is unique but not primary key due to unavoidable reason.

Comment: Not sure why dog isn't marked as the ID if you are going to use it in references. What you mark as the ID for JPA doesn't have to be the database primary key, it only needs to uniquely define the entity (and the JPA spec requires all FKs reference  it so that entities can be cached by ID to maintain object identity over relationships). There are problems with your mapping you need to clean up first: don't use mappedby AND a join column. MappedBy tells JPA to use the mapping from the other side to define the join, which conflicts with your JoinColumn definition.

Comment: Thanks Chris for valuable comments. I used  MappedBy and JoinColumn as relationship is  bidirectional and If @Id annotation on jpa entities need not mapped with database pk I can surely test it.

Comment: Below is the reponse when tried Id annotation :Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: EmbeddedKey must not have @Id properties when used as an -EmbeddedId: EmbeddedKey

Comment: Are you using both the EmbeddedId and ID annotations on ParentEntity? You should switch to using Embedded on embeddedKey with the Id on dog.

Comment: tried your suggestion, it worked. thanks buddy.